# How can i filter and map with Switch Map in one statement?

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have an emitter which emits an array of object which look like this below example.

```
ServerDropdownOption
name: "Just Closed Buyers"
selected: true
value: "leadbucket::07727388-500A-4ED0-BB5A-1BB4718F1AFC"
__proto__: Object
```

the code i am using uses switchMap to only return the value of each object.

```
this.chipsSelect.multiSelectBox.onSave
  pipe(
  takeWhile(_ => this.alive),
  filter((tag) => tag.selected === 'true'),
  switchMap(updatedSelection => this.contactsService.updateBuckets(this.contactId, updatedSelection.map(tag => tag.value))) )
  .subscribe();
```

what i need now is to also filter based on the selected value and also return the ones where that value is true. Problem is that it generates the folowing error.

Property 'selected' does not exist on type 'IOptionMultiSelectBox[]'

```
export interface IOptionMultiSelectBox {
    name: string;
    value: any;
    selected: boolean;
}
```

so my IOptionMultiSelectBox has the selected property but the dat returned from my observable is an array of objects. So how can i fix that so the filter works ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

instead of rxjs `filter`, use `map` and then use JS array.prototype `filter` to fetch the `selected` which are `true`:

```ts
this.chipsSelect.multiSelectBox.onSave
  pipe(
    takeWhile(_ => this.alive),
    map((tags: IOptionMultiSelectBox[]) => tags.filter(tag => tag.selected == true)),
    // .....
```

Comment: can you provide some insight why it complains that the selected does not exist when using the filter ? IOptionMultiSelectBox has that property and what i emit is an Array of those objects so it should exist there as well

Comment: because `selected` does not exist on the `tags` array, it exists in each `tag` in `tags`, but you are trying to use `tags.selected`, which will  not work.

Answer (score 0):

I made it work by actually applying the filter before the emit process

```
save(optionsList: IOptionMultiSelectBox[]) {
this.onSave.emit(optionsList.filter(data => data.selected === true));
this.toggleDirective.close();
}
```

In which case it did not complain about the selected property